# How do i get my program to align like this one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, alignment, currency

im working on this same exact program, but i can't figure out how to make mine align (inputs, costs, $) like this one

[image: program alignment]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you also included your code.

Comment: .. and **not** as an image. Add your code to the question in text form.

Comment: Take a look at the field width modifiers to format specifications.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the individual who wrote the script has simply added a series of " " characters, like the below:

```
print("Not formatted:  £10")
print()
print("      Formatted:        £10")
print(" Also formatted:        £10")
```